# For an $(\infty,1)$-topos, is the object functor from groupoid objects to the topos a fibration, cofibration?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

This question is kind of suggested by the question [Is the category of group objects in an $(\infty,1)$-topos reflective as a subcategory of the groupoid objects?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140639/is-the-category-of-group-objects-in-an-infty-1-topos-reflective-as-a-subcat)

Question: If $\mathcal C$ in an $(\infty,1)$ topos, is the functor from groupoid objects internal to $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal C$ given by the objects in some sense both a fibration and a cofibration? I expect for the latter one needs some kind of natural number object.

In the case of sets, the cofibration property gives for a groupoid $G$ and a function $f: Ob(G) \to Y$ a new groupoid say $f_*(G)$ with object set $Y$ and the appropriate universal property: see Higgins' book [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html). The topological application is the effect  on the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(X,X_0)$ of vertex identifications of a CW-complex $X$.

In particular, if $Y$ is a singleton, we get a group from a groupoid. One can make this construction include free groups and  free products of groups.

Comment: Are you asking if the map $G_0\to |G|$ is a cofibration/fibration?